# Setting up ROS catkin/rosbuild

Tags: bash, ros, catkin

I have both a catkin_ws and a rosbuild_ws. However, when I use the command roscd I can only go to the one I've sourced last, i.e.:

- When I do `source ~/rosbuild_ws/setup.bash`, the packages inside rosbuild are known, hence I can roscd to them.
- When I do `. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`, the packages inside catkin are known. But I stop being able to roscd into rosbuild.

This also means that rosbuild cannot use catkin packages and vice versa.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use multiple workspaces by sourcing the first one as usual and the following ones with the `--extend` flag.
This worked for me with multiple catkin workspaces. Not sure if it will also work with a mixture of catkin and rosbuild but at least it is worth a try:

```
source ~/rosbuild_ws/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash --extend
```